# UIImageView Not Show Image to its Original Image that can available on Server

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

`UIImageView` not show/display Original Image as that of available on server.
for more ref [check it](http://monotouch.2284126.n4.nabble.com/UIImageView-Not-Show-Image-to-its-Original-Image-that-can-available-on-Server-td4656196.html)

```
float scaleFactor = 0.0f;`
float scaleWidth = dstRectangle.Width; //width =748
float scaleHeight = dstRectangle.Height; // height = 759
if(!SizeF.Equals(srcRectangle ,dstRectangle))
{
float widthFactor =(float) dstRectangle.Width / srcRectangle.Width;   //srcRectHeight = 512
float heightFactor =(float) dstRectangle.Height / srcRectangle.Height;  //srcRectangle.Height = 314
if(widthFactor >heightFactor)
scaleFactor = widthFactor ;
else
scaleFactor = heightFactor;
scaleWidth = srcRectangle.Width * scaleFactor;
scaleHeight = srcRectangle.Height * scaleFactor;
if(widthFactor >heightFactor)
           {
thumbnailPoint.Y = (dstRectangle.Height - scaleHeight) * .5f;
}
else


if(widthFactor < heightFactor)
{
thumbnailPoint.X = (dstRectangle.Width - scaleWidth) *.5f;
}
}
UIGraphics.BeginImageContext(new SizeF(dstRectangle.Width , dstRectangle.Height));
RectangleF thumbnailRect = RectangleF.Empty;
thumbnailRect.Offset(thumbnailPoint);
thumbnailRect.Size.Width = scaleWidth;

thumbnailRect.Size.Height = scaleHeight;




CGImage  _bitmap = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext().CGImage;
ImgVIew.Image = UIImage.FromImage(_bitmap);
UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
```

It gives me an UIImage But not display on the UIImageView
In CGImage I got ALphaInfo = PremultipledLast

```
BitsPerComponant = 8

BitsPerPixel =32

BytesPerRow = 3008

Height= 759

Width = 748
```

this values I get into CGImage but this CGImage I conver it to UIImage but still it can not display

Comment: I think you need to post some code.  Otherwise no one is going to be able to help you.

Comment: check it I add some code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just do something like this:

```
        using (var url = NSUrl.FromString ("http://yoururl.com/yourpic.jpg"))
        {
            using (var data = NSData.FromUrl (url))
            {
                imageView.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData (data);
            }
        }
```

It sounds like you just need to download an image and set it to a `UIImageView`, right?

It seems like you are writing a lot of code for something pretty simple.

NOTE: use a try-catch for networking errors.

Comment: my images are RLE compress images while retutning values from LOADFROMDATA(data) methos it returns NULL. so can please tell how I can convert this RLE file to UIImage supported file extension for this I Use CGImage for core height, width it works but images not properly render

Comment: You need to use to some code to decompress the RLE first, then create the image from the decompressed `byte[]`.  A quick glance on google, and I found this class: http://code.google.com/p/dsdecmp/source/browse/trunk/CSharp/DSDecmp/Formats/Nitro/RLE.cs?r=23  There might be a better C# library for RLE compression/decompression out there, but the idea is you would decompress and then create the `UIImage`.